# code igniter email function

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

I have a small question, I have a perfectly working function written in code igniter for sending emails. But what I wanted to know if its possible that if the email sending function has some problems sending email how can I make sure that the other functions in the controller are still running. To be precise, this is my controller.

```
public function CreateMoney($token){        
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
            $alldata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
            $userid = $this->myajax->getUserByAuth($token);
            if ($userid){

                /* some code here */


                $this->db->trans_commit();

                $this->sendEmail();

               /* some more code here */

                $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
                $this->output->set_output(json_encode($invoice));


    } else {
                return $this->output->set_status_header('401', 'Could no identify user!');
    }
        } else {
            return $this->output->set_status_header('400', 'Request not understood as an Ajax request!');
        }    
}
```

So when I click a button it runs this controller code, and then when it goes to the email function it runs this code,

```
public function sendEmail() {
    //fetch tha data from the database 
        $this->load->model('payment_plan');
        $foo = $this->payment_plan->getInfoToNotifyBorrowerForNewLoan();
        $result = json_decode(json_encode($foo[0]), true);

        $this->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

        $config['smtp_port']    = '465';

        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

        $config['smtp_user']    = '*******';

        $config['smtp_pass']    = '*******';

        $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';

        $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

        $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html

        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('*******', '*******');
        $this->email->to($result['Email']);
        $this->email->subject('*******');

        $name               = $result['Fullname'];

        $this->email->message(
            'Hello! '.$name."\n"."\n"



            );  
    $returnvalue = $this->email->send();

    if(!$returnvalue) {
      return false;
    } else {
     $data = array('notified_borrower' => date('Y-m-d'));
     $this->db->update('payment_plan', $data);
     return true;
    }
}
```

So my question is if there is an error in sending the email, like i remove

```
$returnvalue = $this->email->send();
```

from the email function, then there is no sending an email, so how can my controller CreateMoney still run the other some codes even if the email function fails. I tried it by putting return false at the bottom of email function but still when I make a error in the email function on purpose the whole controller function stops. So need a way to make sure that the controller function keeps running even if there is a problem with the email function

Comment: use theis function in your if(!$returnvalue){ $this->email->print_debugger(); to see what's return from the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what `try/catch` blocks are for. You'll find some more information [on Exceptions here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Here's some dummy code:

**In your `CreateMoney()`:**

```
$log = array();
try {
    $this->sendEmail();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $log[] = $e->getMessage();
    // just some stupid dummy code
    // do sth. more useful with it!
}

// afterwards
if (count($log) > 0) {
    // some error occured
    // db has not been updated
}
```

**In your `sendEmail()` function**:

```
// sth. went wrong here
if (!$this->email->send())
    throw new Exception("Could not send email");
else {
    $data = array('notified_borrower' => date('Y-m-d'));
    $this->db->update('payment_plan', $data);
}
```

This way, an email sending can fail and the controller runs nevertheless.

Comment: in the sendEmail() can I write it this way ,
$returnvalue = $this->email->send();
        
        if (!$this->email->send()){
        throw new Exception("Could not send email");
        } else {
         $data = array('notified_borrower' => date('Y-m-d'));
         $this->db->update('payment_plan', $data);
         return true;
        }

Comment: @MasnadNihit Really read the article about exceptions and see my updated answer. You do not really need to return anything with the above approach. The catch block gets only executed when there is an error.

Comment: What happens is that codeigniter is catching the error, so the try/ catch is not working, do you know how I can fix that ?

Comment: I get error saying (string) undefined property in codeigniter

Comment: Jan I used your previous, method and it works! I was messing around with codeigniter so it couldnt send an email, but when I made a error purposely with google username and password in the config then ur thing worked well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MasnadNihit: No worries, glad it helped :-)